# Unable to format python code on VSCode for Macbook

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have followed instructions from multiple sources including the official MS site stackoverflow, but I am still unable to get formatting to work when pressing Option + Shift + F. I am on Mac OS Big Sur 11.3.1, Intel Chip

So far I have tried the following:

**Method 1**

1. Installing Python Extension by MS
2. Installing the Black Formatter by MS
3. Then going into both user settings.json and workspace settings.json and adding
   this

```
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
```

4. My user settings.json and workspace settings.json looks like this now respectively - these lines are the only lines in there

```
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
//user settings.json
```

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    }
}
// workspace settings.json
```

5. Now after doing this, I try to do Option + Shift + F, I see this pop up
   [image]
6. Clicking Configure leads me to a search bar on the top with two options

   1. Black Formatter - ms.python.black-formatter
   2. Python - ms.python

And doesn't matter what I select, nothing happens and when I try Option + Shift + F again after doing this step, I see the same image as on Step 5. This keeps happening.

**Method 2**

1. Did a complete uninstall and install of VSCode
2. Did not install the Python Extension
3. Only installed the Black Formatter
4. Did Steps 3 and 4
5. Tried Option + Shift + F
6. This time, no pop up and no change in the code

How can I get this to work? This is my VSCode Version

```
Version: 1.83.0 (Universal)
Commit: e7e037083ff4455cf320e344325dacb480062c3c
Date: 2023-10-03T16:13:15.449Z (3 wks ago)
Electron: 25.8.4
ElectronBuildId: 24154031
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 20.4.0
```

Comment: Black Formatter did solve issue for me